# ProximityState iPhone Use

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, proximity

What I would like to do is simply make the iDevice fade the screen to black one the proximityState returns yes. However, I am not sure of how to enable it, or monitor it. Would someone be able to simply provide syntax of enabling and monitoring proximityState? 
The help would be highly appreciated for a new programmer like me.

Thanks!
-Jake

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use the `[UIDevice currentDevice]` singleton. First set `proximityMonitoringEnabled` to `YES`. Then, you can access the proximity information through the `proximityState` property. Subscribe to changes to the proximity state by observing the `UIDeviceProximityStateDidChangeNotification` notification.